# Openweathermap api response index out of bounds

Tags: android, json, openweathermap

My Android app is calling the openweathermap geo coding API endpoint with a city name to get its coordinates which are then used to call the onecall endpoint.

I am quite certain the error I am getting is due to a discrepancy between my api response data class and the actual API response but I haven't been able to figure out what part is wrong. The geo coding API call with the values I am using in my app produced this JSON array in Postman:

[http://api.openweathermap.org/geo/1.0/direct?q=Seattle&limit=1&appid={API_KEY}](http://api.openweathermap.org/geo/1.0/direct?q=Seattle&limit=1&appid=%7BAPI_KEY%7D)

```
[
    {
        "name": "Seattle",
        "local_names": {
            "lv": "Sietla",
            "ar": "سياتيل، واشنطن",
            "bs": "Seattle",
            "be": "Сіэтл",
            "kn": "ಸಿಯಾಟಲ್",
            "ko": "시애틀",
            "uk": "Сієтл",
            "en": "Seattle",
            "uz": "Sietl",
            "oc": "Seattle",
            "la": "Seattlum",
            "ja": "シアトル",
            "bg": "Сиатъл",
            "af": "Seattle",
            "fr": "Seattle",
            "zh": "西雅圖",
            "lt": "Sietlas",
            "tt": "Сиэтл",
            "ug": "Séatl",
            "eo": "Seatlo",
            "am": "ስያትል",
            "ru": "Сиэтл"
        },
        "lat": 47.6038321,
        "lon": -122.330062,
        "country": "US",
        "state": "Washington"
    }
]
```

In my app I am calling the endpoints like this:

```
interface WeatherService {
    @GET("/geo/1.0/direct")
    suspend fun getCiyCoordinates(
        @Query("q") cityName: String,
        @Query("limit") limit: Int,
        @Query("appid") apiKey: String): List<CoordinateApiModel>


    @GET("data/3.0/onecall")
    suspend fun getWeather(
        @Query("lat") latitude: Double,
        @Query("lon") longitude: Double,
        @Query("exclude") exclude: String,
        @Query("appid") apiKey: String
    ) : WeatherApiModel

}
data class CoordinateApiModel(
    @Json(name = "lat") val latitude : Double,
    @Json(name = "lon") val longitude : Double
)

class RemoteWeatherDataSourceImpl @Inject constructor(
    private val weatherService: WeatherService,
) : RemoteWeatherDataSource {


    override fun getCoordinates(name: String): Flow<CoordinateApiModel> = flow {
        try {
            val coordinatesList = weatherService.getCiyCoordinates(name, 1, BuildConfig.OWM_KEY)

            if (coordinatesList.isNotEmpty()) {
                val firstCoordinate = coordinatesList[0]
                Log.d(TAG, "First Coordinate: $firstCoordinate")
                emit(firstCoordinate)
            } else {
                throw UseCaseException.WeatherException(Throwable("Coordinates list is empty."))
            }
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Error getting coordinates", e)
            throw UseCaseException.WeatherException(e)
        }
    }


    override fun getWeather(name: String): Flow<WeatherDto> = flow {
        val coordinates = getCoordinates(name).first()
        val weatherData = weatherService.getWeather(coordinates.latitude, coordinates.longitude ,"minutely,daily" ,BuildConfig.OWM_KEY)

        emit(weatherData)
    }.map {weatherApiModel ->
        weatherApiModel.toWeather()
    }.catch {
        throw UseCaseException.WeatherException(it)
    }
```

When running the app though, it crashes and I am getting an index out-of-bounds exception:

```
app.vibecast.domain.entity.UseCaseException$WeatherException: 
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0
                                                                                                        at 

app.vibecast.data.remote.source.RemoteWeatherDataSourceImpl$getWeather$3.invokeSuspend(RemoteWeatherDataSourceImpl.kt:54)
```

Comment: Have you debugged the logic in getCoordinates to see what it returns?